# Hstore error message with simple_form gem - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, hstore

I have a nested form:

```
= simple_form_for(@item) do |f|
  = f.input :name

  -# Nested form
  = f.simple_fields_for :content, OpenStruct.new(@item.content) do |builder| 
    - @item.category.fields.each do |field|
      = render "items/fields/#{field.field_type}", field: field, f: builder
```

I want to display an error message under required field (if it's empty). Currently, in my `Item` model I have a validation block to check if `hstore` field is required and empty or not:

```
serialize :variations, Hash
store_accessor :variations
validate :validate_variations
validates_presence_of :name

def validate_variations
  category.fields.each do |field|
    if field.required? && variations[field.name].blank?
      errors.add field.name, "must not be blank"
    end 
  end
end
```

The code above works perfect if I use a simple error block:

```
- if target.errors.any?
  - target.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
    = message
```

But when I want to user `simple_form` error message, it doesn't trigger anything. My `hstore` field:

```
= f.input field.name, error: "Please enter a valid #{field.name}"
```

Is there any way to display an error message for `hstore` field in `simple_form` underneath the current field?

---

Ruby: `2.7.1`,
Rails: `6.0.3`

Comment: You're missing a closing parens for `OpenStruct.new(@item.content)`. And don't use [`serialize`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html) with JSON/JSONB/HStore or array columns. The PG database driver will handle typecasting for you and using serialize will result in unqueryable data since your shoving a marshaled ruby hash into the database.

Comment: Thank you, `OpenStruck.new` is a typo, I am sorry